# Validate shipping address on place order button click in one page checkout

Tags: magento2, shipping-address, magento2.2.6

Actually I want to validate shipping address form fields when I click on place order button, currently, it validates only email field.

I used [this](https://marketplace.magento.com/espl-onepagecheckout.html) free one-page checkout extension

Does anyone have an idea how can I do this?

[image]